# Execute pipe command in android

Tags: java, android, bash, pipe, exec

I'm executing a command in order to write log messages into a file on the sdcard. This is already working:

```
String command = "logcat -f /storage/sdcard1/test.log";
Process logcatProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Now I want to filter the log output by grep before writing it to the file like this:

```
String[] command = {
        "/system/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "logcat | grep -i Test01 >> /storage/sdcard1/test.log"
    };
Process logcatProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

When I run the code from above the file is created but with no content. The `grep` command is surely installed on the system. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logcat` is outputting to `grep` live, but `grep` is processing data in big batches. Eventually, if there's enough output, `grep` should write something out.

(If you're writing to the terminal instead of to a file, `grep` is slightly less efficient and flushes after every line it sees, making it feel more interactive. This is not specific to Android's `grep`; you'll see this behavior on Linux or OS X also.)

If you use `logcat -d`, it'll terminate instead of polling for more logs, and `grep` will write out and terminate too. If that's not the behavior you want, you may end up needing to use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to wrap `logcat` and re-implement `grep` (without buffering) inside your Java application.